# CSS form submit styling

Tags: css

I am working on a CSS/HTML submit form that I am going to make look like the image below.

I am not sure how to make the Submit button appear like it is inside of the Text input though?

[image]

Comment: Both input fields are probably surrounded by a div and the textbox doesn't have any border.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put a container div that has the exact background color as your text-box. By doing this you can obtain the effect of the button being inside the textbox.

Answer (score 1):

Easy, put it inside a div and style the div to look like an input text. Then you just make the input field have the same background than the div.

Answer (score 0):

I did something similar with my [blog](http://sitesbypalmer.com/blog?post_id=10) for submitting comments using relative positioning. You won't need any extra HTML markup with this method.

Start by placing your submit button directly underneath and on the right side of the text input, then move it upwards with relative positioning into the text input. Something like this should work.

```
input[type="text"] {  <-- Your text input (height comes out to 35px with padding)
    height: 25px;
    padding: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 0;
}

input[type="submit"] { <-- Your submit button (10px shorter for padding)
    height: 25px;
    position: relative;
    bottom: 35px;
    right: 5px;
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-bottom: -30px; <-- To get rid of the empty leftover space.
}
```